# Trouble getting GCHandle.Alloc() to pin a form so handle can be used by native code

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a CE6.0R3 system that uses .NetCF3.5 and uses P/Invoke to interface several native C++ dlls.

These devices crash occassionally and sometimes we see a popup that says "Application myc#app.exe encountered a serious error and must shut down".

One of the things we do is pass a handle to a C# form to a native C++ application that uses DirectShow to render videos on a C# form.

I've been researching it and have found several discussions about using GCHandle to pin managed objects so that they don't move.

I added diagnostics to try and detect if this is the problem as well as added GCHandle.Alloc()s to pin the objects.  For some reason, the objects seem to move in memory even though they should be pinned.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
Diag.Putline("_videoplay create");
_videoplay = new Form();

Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before pinning Handle");
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(_videoplay.Handle, GCHandleType.Pinned);
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before pinning Form");
GCHandle gch_videoplay = GCHandle.Alloc(_videoplay, GCHandleType.Pinned);    // Pin the _videoplay object instance so it won't get moved by GC
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " after pinning");

Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .Location");
_videoplay.Location = new Point(x, y);
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .Size");
_videoplay.Size = new Size(w, h);
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .BackColor");
_videoplay.BackColor = bgColor;
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .FormBorderStyle");
_videoplay.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .Owner");
_videoplay.Owner = _mediaform;
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before .Show()");
_videoplay.Show();
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " after .Show()");

Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " before directshow_connect");
Diag.Putline("directshow_connect");

// P/Invoke to our native C++ application based on this code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899491.aspx
// Pass the handle ot our form that we want to display the video on
// the directshow HWND will be a WS_CHILD of _videoplay
directshow_connect(_videoplay.Handle);
Diag.Putline("_videoplay.Handle = " + _videoplay.Handle + " after directshow_connect");
```

And the output:

```
14:59:37| _videoplay create
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before pinning Handle
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before pinning Form
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 after pinning
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before .Location
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before .Size
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before .BackColor
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191552 before .FormBorderStyle
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879191776 before .Owner
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879192000 before .Show()
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879192000 after .Show()
14:59:37| _videoplay.Handle = 1879192000 before directshow_connect
14:59:37| directshow_connect
14:59:39| _videoplay.Handle = 1879192000 after directshow_connect
14:59:41| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (_TickTockThreadProc)
14:59:41| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (_TickTockThreadProc)
14:59:41| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (UpdateTimer_Tick)
14:59:41| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (UpdateTimer_Tick)
14:59:41| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (_TickTockThreadProc)
14:59:42| _videoplay.Handle = 1879193248 (_TickTockThreadProc)
```

Why does the handle change even though it is pinned?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how a GCHandle works and how it's used.

First, a GCHandle can only be used on a blittable type, so you can't pin a Form itself.  What you're doing is pinning the Handle, which is basically saying to the GC in your code is "do not move the location where you have the address of the Form in memory."  meaning that the storage location of the Handle itself cannot move.  There's nothing to prevent the Form from moving, and thereby the *value* that the Handle holds.

It's a bit odd that the Handle is changing, I would suspect that the Native Form Handle itself can't change once the Form itself is created.  That makes me think that you have a pseudo-handle.  If that were the case, using it in native calls shouldn't work.

I'm not firmly convinced the error is a movement because I'd never seen such behavior before - I'd be more inclined to think it's an attempt to use a Handle of a Disposed Form, but you've been doing the debugging and are likely to have a better feel for it.

At any rate, if you truly believe the failure is due to a handle change then the best workaround is to use a P/Invoke (to CreateWindowEx) to create the container Form itself.  The GC can't move it then, because it doesn't know anything about it.  That would eliminate compaction as the culprit (or fix the problem).